# Generics and Types and Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

Can a 'generic type' be an array?

And in the cases where it is, how can one access that array?

Can you access a given generic type T as an array, when it is one, and as a non-array when it is not one?

For instance:

If I had a method like ->

```
void MustBeOfType<T>(T value){}
```

Can I have ->

```
MustBeOfType<int>(10);
```

And Also ->

```
MustBeOfType<int[]>( new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

And within those generic methods, can they access the values as one would expect? - one as an int and one as an int[]?

I think there might be something with typeof(T).IsArray()... but I just can't for the life of me figure out how to cast the parameter as an array when it is one.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you expecing to be able to 'access' the value within the function?

Comment: Sounds like you want a series of overloads.

Comment: @Lee one could do something disgusting like have a series of `if ( value is int )` ... `if ( value is List<double> )` etc. - and it'd work - but it'd go against the whole point of having generics in the first place.

Comment: Expanding on @WaiHaLee's comment, have `MustBeOfType<T>(T value)` and `MustBeOfType<T>(T[] value)` and the appropriate one will be called based on the passed in type.

Answer (score 1):

You could...but, I'm not sure you should:

```
void MustBeOfType<T>(T value)
{
  Array array = value as Array;
  if (array != null) //It is an array
  {
    foreach (var arrayItem in array)
    {
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
      var arrayItem = array.GetValue(i);
    }
  }
  else //It is not an array
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but Generic types can be anything. You can put restrictions to your generic type with `where` clause, but this is up to you and up to functionality and context.

Lets take List as example. Let say that we have List inside List. Then we define it as:

```
List<List<string>> myListOfList = new List<List<string>>();
```

your must be of type can also be anything ( if you didnt put restriction with where clause)

```
MustBeOfType<int[][]>()
MustBeOfType<List<List<string>>>()
MustBeOfType<AnyOtherGenericClass<List<string>>>()
```

and to be able to access it:

```
class MustBeOfType<T>
{
    private T _value;
    MustBeofType(T value)
    {
         _value = value;
    }

}
```

to be able to make operation on , you can use reflection or if you put where restriction and your where restriction has Type, then you can see properties of that Type.